# Unable to fetch video player elements in appium

Tags: java, testing, video, appium, media-player

I am trying to automate an android app that provides media content on OTT, say like netflix.

Now the automation tool I am using is Appium with java.

I am unable to validate the video player parameters. As soon as the video player is launched, the UI automator is unable to fetch the screenshot of the device.

I have been stuck with this for a while now. Would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and the reason behind it was "uiAutomator waits for app to be an idle state before fetching the elements".
The **workaround** to get the elements of player will be to pause the video playback and then fetch rest of the elements on page, to pause the video playback you can [use android media key events](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=21432553#content/view/21432553) as it won't  require you to perform any action on the app screen.